# Нужно ли заключать в кавычки слово после "называли" или "называется"?

Tags: кавычки

Правильно ли расставлены кавычки в данном предложении: *Во время Великой Отечественной войны установку БМ-13 называли «Катюшей», а какое оружие называли «Папашей»?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как мне кажется, кавычки стоят верно, потому что в русском языке одной из функций кавычек является выделение условных (собственных) наименований. Если я не прав, пусть более опытные пользователи меня поправят.

Одним из семантических групп условных наименований, заключаемых в кавычки, являются названия средств покорения космоса, **военной техники**: шаттл «Дискавери», челнок «Атлантис», узловой модуль «Причал», баллистическая ракета «Тополь», зенитный ракетный комплекс «Бук», ударный комплекс «Искандер-М».

---

Реальные собственные имена и условные наименования различаются синтаксической сочетаемостью. Ср.: Большой театр, Театр сатиры, Театр на Юго-Западе – это реальные собственные имена, в них присутствует синтаксическая сочетаемость, кавычки не нужны. Но: театр «Современник», театр «Школа современной пьесы» – условные наименования, не сочетающиеся синтаксически с родовым словом. Они заключаются в кавычки. Аналогично: парк Дружбы, но: парк «Сокольники», Коммунистическая партия Российской Федерации, но: партия «Яблоко» и т. д.

Обратите внимание: реальные собственные имена тоже могут употребляться в сочетании с родовым наименованием (чаще всего – обозначением организационно-правовой формы) и при этом заключаться в кавычки, но при употреблении без родового наименования они, в отличие от условных названий, пишутся без кавычек, ср.:

1. Московская типография № 2 и ОАО «Московская типография № 2»;
2. Российская академия народного хозяйства и государственной службы при Президенте Российской Федерации и федеральное государственное бюджетное образовательное учреждение высшего образования «Российская академия народного хозяйства и государственной службы при Президенте Российской Федерации»;
3. Президентская библиотека имени Б. Н. Ельцина и федеральное государственное бюджетное учреждение «Президентская библиотека имени Б. Н. Ельцина»;
4. Город воинской славы и почетное звание «Город воинской славы».

**Более подробно:** http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/75-kav2